# Calculation of a delivery date

Tags: php

I would like to calculate the date of a delivery according to several parameters:

We are for example the Monday 28th of January. My carrier has a minimum date of 3 days and 5 days maximum so my delivery should be between Thursday 31 January and 4 February because the additional constraint is that this carrier does not deliver Saturday and Sunday. I am looking to do a php function that calculates this date, however i have carriers that book on saturday so if the carrier delivers on saturday the delivery will be between january 31st and february 2nd. Here are some variables that I have:

```
$minDays = (int)$carrierDefault->delay_min;
    $maxDays = (int)$carrierDefault->delay_max;
    $saturdayDelivery = $carrierDefault->delivered_saturday;
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Add 10 (or other must-deliver max date), now have array of dates that is between current date and max. Loop it and check if it's valid date for delivering, if not - remove it from your array. After that you have all valid dates range, take 3rd and 5th elements from array to show dates to client

Comment: 28/01 is monday , and 31/01 is  Thursday , where is sunday and saturday here ? why delivery can't start in Tuesday ?

Comment: the minimum delivery date is 3 days the possible delivery date is between the 31 and the 4

Answer (score 0):

May this help you:

```php
    <?php
       function isWeekend($date , $ignore_saturday=false) {
    $weekDay = date('w', strtotime($date));
    return ($weekDay == 0 || ($weekDay == 6 && !$ignore_saturday) ) ;
}



function selectDeliveryinterval($startDate, $min_delivery = 3, $max_delivery = 5 , $ignore_saturday=false) {
    $isfull = true;
    $counter = 0;
    $dates = array();

    while($isfull) {
        $startDate->modify('+1 day');
        if(!isWeekend($startDate->format('Y-m-d'),$ignore_saturday)) {
            $dates[] = clone $startDate;
            $counter++;
        }

        if($counter == $max_delivery) {
            $isfull = false;
        }
    }

    // the array contain the dates in the delivery interval 
    return [$dates[$min_delivery - 1], $dates[$max_delivery - 1]];
}

$date = new DateTime('2019-01-28');
$res = selectDeliveryinterval($date,3,5,true);

echo 'your delivery date min is '.$res[0]->format('Y-m-d');

echo 'your delivery date max is '.$res[1]->format('Y-m-d');
```

Output:

> your delivery date min is 2019-02-20
>
> your delivery date max is 2019-02-22

In case the carriers work on saturday :

> your delivery date min is 2019-01-31
>
> your delivery date max is 2019-02-02

Comment: Thanks for cons if the deliveryman delivers on Saturday his does not work

Comment: i d'ont get on what you say ?

Comment: I find for Saturday against it is possible to add that if we are on Friday deliveries will only be sent from Monday the coup. we are Friday, the min is 3 days so Thursday delivery. Thank you.

Comment: what's the     $saturdayDelivery = $carrierDefault->delivered_saturday; return ? a boolean ?

Comment: check now  , just add a new parameter "true" fr selectDeliveryinterval methd to check if carrier work on saturday or not .